# Download artifact for all pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a `C# solution` with multiple executable projects and I want to do a pipeline to build exe files and dependencies and another pipeline to generate multiple installers using Advanced Installer.

Release pipeline is triggered by the artifact of first build pipeline. As I have noticed if I don't disable it, the pipeline starts automatically checking out the repository. I have disabled it and doing the artifact download in the first job.

I want to know if it's possible to download artifact only once and have it available for all jobs in same stage and not write same `checkout: none` and `download` in all jobs.

```
trigger: none

pool:
   name: Default
   demands: 
   - Agent.Name -equals SelfHostedAgent

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'repoCi' 
    source: '\Folder\Repo-CI' 
    trigger: true 

stages:
- stage: WPF

  jobs:
  - job: 'GetVersions'
    steps:
    - checkout: none
      clean: true

    - download: 'repoCi'
      artifact: 'WPF'
    
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Get Exe Versions'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | # Get Versions in powershell

  - job: InstallerJob1
    dependsOn: 'GetVersions'
    condition: succeeded('GetVersions')

    steps:
    - checkout: none

    - download: 'repoCi'
      artifact: 'WPF'


- stage: Xamarin
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:

    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.
          Write-Host "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps Pipelines, each job creates its own workspace on the agent where the source and other files are downloaded. That means each job will need to define what is downloaded and what is not. There is no option to let you globally define what sources/artifacts are downloaded for all jobs across your repository.

Keep in mind that you also don't necessarily need to split up your pipeline into lots of jobs, you can instead keep more tasks in a single job. There are of course good reasons to have multiple jobs, but if you can't think of a good reason as to why you want to have it split in multiple jobs, consider keeping it within one job to save repeating the download of artifacts.

One option to clean it up a little bit (but also adds more complexity) is to move your source and artifact downloads into a template, and then you can reference that at the start of each of your jobs instead.

`main.yaml`

```
stages:
- stage: WPF

  jobs:
  - job: 'GetVersions'
    steps:
    - template: "source-and-artifact.yaml"
    
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Get Exe Versions'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | # Get Versions in powershell

  - job: InstallerJob1
    dependsOn: 'GetVersions'
    steps:
    - template: "source-and-artifact.yaml"
```

`source-and-artifact.yaml`

```
    steps:
    - checkout: none
      clean: true

    - download: 'repoCi'
      artifact: 'WPF'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if it's possible to download artifact only once and have it available for all jobs in same stage and not write same checkout: none and download in all jobs.

Yes. This is possible when using Self-hosted agent.

From your YAML Sample, all jobs are running on the Same self-hosted agent(name: SelfHostedAgent).

In this case, you can define the **Download path** of the **Download Pipeline artifacts task**.

For example:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    buildType: 'current'
    downloadType: 'single'
    artifactName: 'drop'
    downloadPath: 'C:/'
```

**Note:** You need to use the [DownloadBuildArtifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines) or [DownloadPipelineArtifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines). They supports define the download path. The [abbreviated download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-download?view=azure-pipelines) does not support defining paths.

All jobs running on the same agent can download artifacts once to a shared path, and then other jobs can access them directly.

For example:

```
pool:
   name: Default
   demands: 
   - Agent.Name -equals SelfHostedAgent

variables:
 downloadPath: C:/test

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: 'repoCi' 
    source: '\Folder\Repo-CI' 
    trigger: true 

stages:
- stage: WPF

  jobs:
  - job: 'GetVersions'
    steps:
    - checkout: none
      clean: true


    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        downloadPath: '$(downloadPath)'

    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Get Exe Versions'
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: | # Get Versions in powershell

  - job: InstallerJob1
    dependsOn: 'GetVersions'
    condition: succeeded('GetVersions')

    steps:
    - checkout: none


- stage: Xamarin
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps:

    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.
          Write-Host "Hello World"
```

In this case, the build artifacts will download to C:/test folder. Then all jobs can directly access this folder to get the files in build artifacts.

Comment: I have noticed that almost in selfhosted agen the workspace is not deleted across jobs unless I have selected it. So in practice I can skip download artifact again. But maybe this is not the best option if each job have their own workspace. I have reached a maybe better option. Use pattern parameter to download only what I need in each job. The same applies to checkout? Each job have to do their own checkout?

Comment: @JuanDYB The checkout step has no same function(checkout part of the repo) as the download artifacts step. If you need to achieve this feature, you need to skip checkout step and use git command to achieve it. Refer to this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71060689/pull-only-one-folder-from-get-repository-git-from-azure-pipelines

Comment: On the other hand, if you need to use the repo files in each job, you need to checkout them in each job.  I suggest that you can create a temp folder in Agent folder, then you can checkout the repo and artifacts to the same folder once in the first job. The other jobs can use the same folder. Then in the final job, you can add [delete files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/delete-files-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task to delete the folder.

Comment: Each job has a separate workspace, which is expected. This can avoid conflicts between workflows in different job